# String matching within a list of lists

Tags: r, regex

I have list, which holds a number of lists containing character vectors. I want to return the index of the lists where one or more of the elements within one or more of the character vectors contains a pattern.

The structure is like this:

```
fruits <- list(
  list(c("apple", "orange", "pear")),
  list(c("pear", "orange", "lemon")),
  list(c("lemon", "orange", "grape")),
  list(c("pineapple", "lemon", "grape"),
       c("orange", "grape", "pear"))
)
```

If I use grep as below, I get the index of the first list, but it also picks up 'pineapple' in the fourth list:

```
fruit <- "apple"
grep(fruit, fruits)
```

I want to specify that the index returned should only be for exact matches i.e. **I would like only the index of the first list when matching 'apple'**.

Something like below, which doesn't work as I think the character vectors are being evaluated as one string:

```
grep(paste0("^","apple","$"), fruits)
```

Comment: `sapply(fruits, function(x) any(grepl(fruit, x)))`

Comment: or for exact 
`sapply(fruits, function(x) any(unlist(x) == fruit))`

Comment: I just want the index of the list that contains 'apple', not 'pineapple' as well

Comment: Don't use `grep` when you want to do exact match. try `which(sapply(fruits, function(x) any(unlist(x) == fruit)))`

Comment: @RonakShah Why is that?

Comment: Because `grep` is for oattern matching but here you are doing exact matching.